# Using each() with JSONP results

Tags: jquery, api, jsonp, each

I am using the themoviedb.org API which provides JSONP API that returns data for films etc.

Am trying to create a form that you can search a film and it will return 5 most relevant movie titles based on the query.

Currently I am using:

```
           success: function(parsed_json) {
               console.log(parsed_json);

               $(".search").append("<li data-id=" +parsed_json["results"]["0"]["id"]+ ">" + parsed_json["results"]["0"]["original_title"] + "</li>");
               $(".search").append("<li data-id=" +parsed_json["results"]["1"]["id"]+ ">" + parsed_json["results"]["1"]["original_title"] + "</li>");
               $(".search").append("<li data-id=" +parsed_json["results"]["2"]["id"]+ ">" + parsed_json["results"]["2"]["original_title"] + "</li>");
               $(".search").append("<li data-id=" +parsed_json["results"]["3"]["id"]+ ">" + parsed_json["results"]["3"]["original_title"] + "</li>");
               $(".search").append("<li data-id=" +parsed_json["results"]["4"]["id"]+ ">" + parsed_json["results"]["4"]["original_title"] + "</li>");
               $(".search").append("<li data-id=" +parsed_json["results"]["5"]["id"]+ ">" + parsed_json["results"]["5"]["original_title"] + "</li>");
           }
```

to append all movie titles with data-id = the movie id. This seems to be ALOT of coding and I was wondering whether there is a way I could use each() to append the first 5 relevant movie titles.

Info on the JSONP API: http://help.themoviedb.org/kb/api/jsonp

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/javascript/5ApuF/

***EDIT:***

I have tried:

```
success: function(parsed_json) {
    var textToInsert = [];
    var i = 0;
    var length = parsed_json.length;
    for (var a = 0; a <length; a += 1) {
        textToInsert[i++]  = '<li>';
        textToInsert[i++] = parsed_json[a];
        textToInsert[i++] = '</li>' ;
     
    }
    $('.search').append(textToInsert.join(''));

}
```

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: BTW, the best way to do this is using a templating engine such as Knockout

Comment: @Slaks I would prefer to stick with only 1 library such as jQuery instead of bloating it up. As for what I have tried but didnt work was to use: check edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this should work just fine for your needs...

```
success: function(parsed_json) {
    console.log(parsed_json);
    if (k > 4) {
        return false;
    }
    $.each(parsed_json["results"], function(k, v) {
         $(".search").append("<li data-id=" +v["id"]+ ">" + v["original_title"] + "</li>");
    });
}
```

Goodluck!  I edited this because I forgot you wanted only 5 results :)

--al

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for (result in parsed_json["results"]) {
    $(".search").append("<li data-id=" +parsed_json["results"][result]["id"]+ ">" + parsed_json["results"][result]["original_title"] + "</li>");
}
```